# Overflowed element with fixed position parent

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a CSS grid-layout as you can see:

```js
        $( ".sidebar-toggle" ).click(function() {
            $(".page-with-sidebar").toggleClass("collapsed");
        });
```

```css
.page-with-sidebar {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 240px 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "sidebar content";
}

.page-with-sidebar.collapsed {
  grid-template-columns: 48px 1fr;
}

.ff-sidebar-container {
  grid-area: sidebar;
}

.ff-sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 240px;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  grid-area: sidebar;
  background-color: powderblue;

  <!-- THIS IS THE PROBLEM LINE ======================= -->
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.page-with-sidebar.collapsed .ff-sidebar {
  width: 48px;
}

#sidebar-logo {
  width: 240px;
  height: 80px;
}

#sidebar-logo #logo-big {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  padding: 12px;
  margin: 0 0 32px 0;
}

#sidebar-logo #logo-small {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  padding: 12px;
  margin: 0 0 32px 0;
}

#sidebar-logo #logo-small {
  display: block;
}

#sidebar-logo #logo-small {
  display: none;
}

.page-with-sidebar.collapsed #sidebar-logo #logo-small {
  display: block;
}

.page-with-sidebar.collapsed #sidebar-logo #logo-big {
  display: none;
}

.sidebar-link {
  display: grid;
  position: relative;
  grid-template: 48px / 48px 192px;
  grid-template-areas: "icon label";
  align-items: center;
}

.sidebar-link span {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  padding: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
}

.sidebar-link label {
  align-self: center;
  padding: 12px 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sidebar-links summary {
  position: relative;
}

.sidebar-links summary::after {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  top: 16px;
  right: 16px;
  content: "";
  padding: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  color: black;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sidebar-links details[open] summary::after {
  transform: rotate(225deg);
  top: 22px;
}

.page-with-sidebar.collapsed summary::after,
.page-with-sidebar.collapsed .sidebar-link label {
  display: none;
}

.page-with-sidebar.collapsed .sidebar-link:hover > label {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: normal;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 2px 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.ff-content-container {
  grid-area: content;
  padding: 0 2vw;
}

::-webkit-details-marker {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class="page-with-sidebar">

    <div class="ff-sidebar-container">
        <nav class="ff-sidebar">
            <a id="sidebar-logo" class="sidebar-toggle">
                <img id="logo-big"  />
                <img id="logo-small"  />
            </a>

            <div class="sidebar-links">
                <details>
                    <summary>
                        <a class="sidebar-link" data-scroll href="#section-intro">
                            <span>
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                                    <polyline points="22 12 18 12 15 21 9 3 6 12 2 12"/>
                                </svg>
                            </span>
                            <label><strong>Start</strong></label>
                        </a>
                    </summary>
                    
                    <a class="sidebar-link">
                        <span>
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                                <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="4"/>
                            </svg>
                        </span>
                        <label>One</label>
                    </a>
                    
                    <a class="sidebar-link">
                        <span>
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                                <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="4"/>
                            </svg>
                        </span>
                        <label>Two</label>
                    </a>
                    
                    <a class="sidebar-link">
                        <span>
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                                <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="4"/>
                            </svg>
                        </span>
                        <label>Three</label>
                    </a>
                  
                    <a class="sidebar-link">
                        <span>
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                                <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="4"/>
                            </svg>
                        </span>
                        <label>Five</label>
                    </a>
                  
                    <a class="sidebar-link">
                        <span>
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                                <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="4"/>
                            </svg>
                        </span>
                        <label>Six</label>
                    </a>
                  
                    <a class="sidebar-link">
                        <span>
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                                <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="4"/>
                            </svg>
                        </span>
                        <label>Seven</label>
                    </a>
                  
                    <a class="sidebar-link">
                        <span>
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                                <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="4"/>
                            </svg>
                        </span>
                        <label>Eight</label>
                    </a>
                  
                    <a class="sidebar-link">
                        <span>
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                                <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="4"/>
                            </svg>
                        </span>
                        <label>Eight</label>
                    </a>
                  
                    <a class="sidebar-link">
                        <span>
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                                <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="4"/>
                            </svg>
                        </span>
                        <label>Nine</label>
                    </a>
                  
                    <a class="sidebar-link">
                      <span>
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                                <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="4"/>
                            </svg>
                        </span>
                      <label>Ten</label>
                    </a>
                </details>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="ff-content-container">
        <section id="section-intro">
            <div class="row padding-top-small margin-bottom-small">
                <div class="portion whole">
                    <div class="border-thick margin-bottom-tiny"></div>
                    <h4>01 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</h4>
                </div>
              
              <div class="portion whole">
                    <div class="border-thick margin-bottom-tiny"></div>
                    <h4>02 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</h4>
                </div>
              
              <div class="portion whole">
                    <div class="border-thick margin-bottom-tiny"></div>
                    <h4>03 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</h4>
                </div>
              
              <div class="portion whole">
                    <div class="border-thick margin-bottom-tiny"></div>
                    <h4>04 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</h4>
                </div>
              
              <div class="portion whole">
                    <div class="border-thick margin-bottom-tiny"></div>
                    <h4>05 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</h4>
                </div>
              
              <div class="portion whole">
                    <div class="border-thick margin-bottom-tiny"></div>
                    <h4>06 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</h4>
                </div>
              
              <div class="portion whole">
                    <div class="border-thick margin-bottom-tiny"></div>
                    <h4>07 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Basic setup—

- A collapsible sidebar on the left, and content on the right. Collapse
  is triggered by clicking the white box on the top of the sidebar.
- The sidebar collapse basically alters the `grid-template-columns` property of
  the page.
- Sidebar has a HTML `details` and `summary` element that opens and collapses.
- Sidebar links each have an icon and a label.
- Once sidebar is collapsed, only the icon is visible, and the label is displayed as a badge on hovering over the link, via `postion: absolute`.

Now, my problem is that if I enable `overflow-y: scroll` on the sidebar, this `label` gets hidden. How can I keep the intended behaviour of the `label`, AND have the sidebar scroll too?

**What needs to happen:**

[image]

---

**What is actually happening, once I enable `overflow-y: scroll` on the sidebar**

[image]

It is basically not allowing overflow in a single direction alone. I am open to simple JS solutions too, if it'll get the job done.

Comment: Please don't post your code to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time and then no one can understand your question. You can just include a "code snippet" right here in your question.

Comment: Ah, right, thanks! Will keep that in mind, thanks again for the edit!

Comment: Can you provide the class name which you apply overflow-y: scroll

Comment: `.ff-sidebar`. It's on line 21 of the above code, if you toggle that declaration, you can see the above behaviour.